# Blurry icons in Excel 365 JS add-in

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, office-store

Our team proceeds with developing an JS add-in for Excel 365 Online and Desktop.

We noticed that the icons in add-ins ribbon look blurry on retina displays.
For example, look at Script Lab add-in ribbon screenshot. It is noticeable that the icons are blurry too.
[image]

Is there a way to specify a separate url for images for retina in the manifest.xml file?

Maybe, it is possible to specify the other size for the pictures for the retina displays (i.e. for non-retina screen we will show icons with a size 32x32px, and for retina we will show 64x64px images)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I was using only the required sizes of 16, 32, and 80 and the ribbon icons looked awful.  Adding a size of 64 made it look much nicer.

Answer (score 0):

You can define bigger icons in the manifest file. See the [Sizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-icons-monoline#sizes) section for the supported dimensions:

> We recommend that you produce each icon in all these sizes to support high DPI devices. The absolutely required sizes are 16 px, 20 px, and 32 px, as those are the 100% sizes.

```
16 px, 20 px, 24 px, 32 px, 40 px, 48 px, 64 px, 80 px, 96 px
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

We have already used images with sizes 16, 32 and 80 px according to documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/resources#images).
Are you sure that we can use 96 px image in manifest for Excel add-in?

Also, we would really appreciate any additional ideas how to display icons on high DPI screens.

Comment: I have mentioned the page where icons are described. There is specific property for that.

Comment: @sveta_d 's link contradicts your link and I think the info in her link is correct.  I have seen that elsewhere.  I wish Microsoft was better about updating outdated content.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using the High Resolution Icon Url in the manifest to control the image that is used to represent your Office Add-in in the insertion UX and Office Store on high DPI screens

[More here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/highresolutioniconurl)

Comment: It looks like HighResolutionIconUrl is used to represent logo of the Office Add-in. But we need High Resolution icons for buttons in the ribbon. Is it possible to use other icons for ribbon in case if a user has a retina screen?

Comment: > is it used to represent your Office Add-in in the insertion UX and Office Store on high DPI screens

Comment: The question is about ribbon icons/images.